# Remove element from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json array which looks something like this:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "children": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "children": {
            "id": 3,
            "children": {
                "id": 4,
                "children": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "children": {
            "id": 3,
            "children": {
                "id": 4,
                "children": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "children": {
            "id": 3,
            "children": {
                "id": 4,
                "children": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "children": {
            "id": 3,
            "children": {
                "id": 4,
                "children": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "children": {
            "id": 3,
            "children": {
                "id": 4,
                "children": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "children": {
            "id": 3,
            "children": {
                "id": 4,
                "children": ""
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "children": {
            "id": 3,
            "children": {
                "id": 4,
                "children": ""
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

I would like to have a function which removes the elements which has the "children" empty. How can I do it? I am not asking for the answer, only suggestions

Comment: Careful: those `=` signs hint at invalid JSON

Comment: @magritte stop with this redundant question. he said he is asking for suggestions. not the answer/

Comment: @rjz , yes those = should be : ...

Comment: i know that is not a valid json ... i just wanted to give an example of how it looks.

Comment: @StackOverfolow dont worry. you are allowed to be wrong. this is why we  are here.I made your JSON into a valid one. continue from here.

Comment: @StackOverfolow Can you show some less-vague data? There are multiple "children" keys here at different levels. What `children` are you pointing to?

Comment: If you say you've got an array, please post an array. And check out the [`filter` array function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To iterate through the keys of an object, use a `for .. in` loop:

```
for (var key in json_obj) {
    if (json_obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do something with `key'
    }
}
```

To test all elements for empty children, you can use a recursive approach: iterate through all elements and recursively test their children too.

Removing a property of an object can be done by using the `delete` keyword:

```
var someObj = {
    "one": 123,
    "two": 345
};
var key = "one";
delete someObj[key];
console.log(someObj); // prints { "two": 345 }
```

Documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: +1 ... I've been coding in Javascript for years and I didn't even know the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator existed?!

Comment: I think he should use the splice() method rather than delete since the children are held in an array?

Comment: @magritte He has listen both arrays and objects. I'm waiting for some clarification, but yes, if there are arrays he can use `splice` to remove elements or use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to iterate and remove stuff.

Comment: +1 it is the place to clear out that delete wont delete an array element from array but replace it with undefined. delete is only for deleting props from object.

Answer (score 3):

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fP7NS/)

```
function deleteEmpty(obj){
        for(var k in obj)
         if(k == "children"){
             if(obj[k]){
                     deleteEmpty(obj[k]);
             }else{
                   delete obj.children;
              } 
         }
    }

for(var i=0; i< a.children.length; i++){
 deleteEmpty(a.children[i])
}
```