# Removing {"data":} from a API response

Tags: javascript, json

if I have a JSON object say:

```
var myObj = {'data' : {'key1' : 'value', 'key2': 'value'}}
```

can I remove `{'data':}` so it becomes:

`{'key1' : 'value','key2': 'value'`}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove key-value pair from JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770887/remove-key-value-pair-from-json-object)

Comment: @MoinShirazi I don't want to remove key-value pair i wanted to remove the first key along with those curly braces.Possibly not s duplicate .

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
myObj = myObj.data;
```

You will then have a `myObj` that is just this:

```
{'key1' : 'value', 'key2': 'value'}
```