# How can I add a key/value pair to a nested object literal?

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal

**SOLVED, the function this code exists in is being called more often then expected, due to this the values can be undefined and therefor the adding values to the nested object literal won't work. My solution was to check whether the `response.times is defined` and only in this case add the values.**

I'm currently having a bit of trouble where I'm trying to add key-value pairs to an object within a javascript object.

I mainly looked at the solutions in the following topic, because I couldn't find anything closer to my question.

[How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770887/remove-key-value-pair-from-json-object)

I'm in a situation where I get an object returned with a bunch or executiontimes which I use in order to determine where my application gets slow (server, database, query etc.). However all of these times have been present in the response object which is passed from the server.

In order to change this I made a specific object within the response for all of these times. The problem is I still add all of these timestamps to the main response object before I change them into this object.

```
response.times = {
  'executionTime': response.executionTime,
  'processingTime': response.processingTime,
}
```

I would like to be able to add of all these timestamps  to this object as soon as they are known.

Adding the values to the response object can be done in multiple ways:

```
response.executionTime = 'x';
response['executionTime'] = 'x';
Object.assign(response, {executionTime: 'x'});
response.push({executionTime: 'x'});
```

But none of these methods work in a case where I'm trying to do something like this, the errors I'm getting in these codes are `Cannot read property ... of undefined` . In all of the cases times seems undefined even though there are values set to it.

```
response.times.executionTime = 'x';
response.times['executionTime'] = 'x';
Object.assign(response.times, {executionTime: 'x'});
Object.assign(response['times]', {executionTime: 'x'});
response.times.push({executionTime: 'x'});
response['times'].push({executionTime: 'x'});
```

Is there a correct way to get this done?

Comment: it is hard to understand the relation between all those codes... But my guess is that you simply do not define response.times

Comment: Have you get some erros?

Comment: Object.assign(response['times]' {executionTime: 'x'}); has errors, typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure *response* and *response.times* are objects or empty objects instead of *null*, *undefined*, ... :

```js
  var response;
  response = response || {};
  response.times = response.times || {};
  response.times.executionTime = 'x';
  console.log(response);
```

Comment: This seems a logical solution, but I'm still receiving a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'executionTime' of undefined`

Comment: Snippet is working and correct, the code always been right, my code had flaws as there were cases where it had been undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Here your code works (I removed the `.push()` ones since they are for arrays). You just need to define the `response` object, and the `response.times` object before adding the properties.

```js
response = {
  times: {}
};
response.times.executionTime1 = 'x';
response.times['executionTime2'] = 'x';
Object.assign(response.times, {
  executionTime3: 'x'
});
Object.assign(response['times'], {
  executionTime4: 'x'
});

console.log(response);
```

Comment: This however clears the response (and times) object which is not meant to happen (re-added comment as I removed the wrong one).

Comment: Yes, you are right. All depends on the need and the context, which was not provided. Glad you got it fixed!