# How to remove properties (key:values) from JSON object in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have JSON that looks like:

```
[
    {
        WWW: "2",
        XXX: "2",
        YYY: "3",
        ZZZ: "4"
    },
    {
        WWW: "2",
        XXX: "5",
        YYY: "6",
        ZZZ: "7"
    },
    {
        WWW: "2",
        XXX: "2",
        YYY: "2",
        ZZZ: "3"
    }
]
```

But I'm only interested in working with and Y and Z.

Howe can I remove the entire W and X columns either from the raw JSON or from the JSON in the form of an Array in SWIFT?

Only answers I can find such [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770887/remove-key-value-pair-from-json-object) seem outdated. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Decode the JSON with `JSONDecoder`(one of the top `swift` questions here on SO) and specify the CodingKeys you want to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
dict["WWW"] = nil
dict["XXX"] = nil
```

or:

```
dict.removeValue(forKey: "WWW")
dict.removeValue(forKey: "XXX")
```

Better Approach would be using `JSONEncoder` and `CodingKeys`.

```
struct Model: Decodable {
    var yyy, zzz: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case yyy = "YYY", zzz = "ZZZ"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your struct to match what you want, and then decode it:

```
struct Value: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case y = "YYY"
        case z = "ZZZ"
    }
    var y: String
    var z: String
}

let value = try JSONDecoder().decode([Value].self, from: json)
```

This will exclude any keys you don't include.