# Convert some part of json to arry using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, web-services

I am getting issue and want to convert it into array manually using JavaScript.

```
{
    "code" :"1", 
    "data" : { 
        "0" : {"id":"1","score":"44"},
        "1" : {"id":"1","score":"44"}
    }
}
```

I want above that in this format:

```
{
    "code": "1",
    "data": [
        {"id": "1","score": "44"},
        {"id": "2"," score": "45"}
    ]
}
```

I tried using [Remove element from JSON Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451290/remove-element-from-json-object) and [Converting JSON Object into Javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20881213/converting-json-object-into-javascript-array).

However, it is not getting up to the mark, so I'm still trying my best. If somebody has solution please let me know.

Comment: please show us what you've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var json =  {
   "code" :"1", 
   "data" : { 
    "0" : {"id":"1","score":"44"},
    "1" : {"id":"1","score":"44"}
    }
};

var dataArray = Object.keys(json.data).map(function (i) {
    return json.data[i];
});

json.data = dataArray;
```

Comment: `Object.keys` is not supported in IE8 and below

Comment: @AdamAzad Where did you find the restriction that IE8 has to be supported? I can't find one...

Comment: @AdamAzad IE8 is an unsupported browser. Unless specified, answers don't have to cater to legacy browser versions.

Comment: @AdamAzad I think Andreas is asking where OP says needs IE8 support in Question

Comment: Well you can use `for-in` in that case.

Comment: Thanks your code helped me.