# Copy elements object to another object Javascript / Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, object

i want to copy some elements from an object to another object

I have this :

```
var arrLinks = [
              {
                titulo: "CUADERNO DE BONOS SEGUROS BX+ 2020",
                fecha: "2020-02-18 11:02:41.0",
                categoria: "BONOS E INCENTIVOS",
                descripcion: "Cuaderno de Bonos e Incentivos"               
              },
              {
                titulo: "ACTUALIZACIÓN TARIFA AUTOS / PICKUP 2019",
                fecha: "2019-07-22 10:57:43.0",
                categoria: "CIRCULARES",
                descripcion: "Actualización de tarifa para Seguro de Auto B×+ y Seguro de Pick Up B×+ 2019"             
              },
              {
                titulo: "AVISO DE ACCIDENTES O ENFERMEDAD - GMM",
                fecha: "2019-09-18 12:42:45.0",
                categoria: "SINIESTROS PERSONAS",
                descripcion: "Aviso de Accidentes o Enfermedad Gastos Médicos Mayores"              
              }           
            ];
```

I want to have this:

```
var arrLinks2 = [
          {
            titulo: "CUADERNO DE BONOS SEGUROS BX+ 2020",               
            categoria: "BONOS E INCENTIVOS",
            descripcion: "Cuaderno de Bonos e Incentivos"               
          },
          {
            titulo: "ACTUALIZACIÓN TARIFA AUTOS / PICKUP 2019",             
            categoria: "CIRCULARES",
            descripcion: "Actualización de tarifa para Seguro de Auto B×+ y Seguro de Pick Up B×+ 2019"             
          },
          {
            titulo: "AVISO DE ACCIDENTES O ENFERMEDAD - GMM",               
            categoria: "SINIESTROS PERSONAS",
            descripcion: "Aviso de Accidentes o Enfermedad Gastos Médicos Mayores"              
          }           
        ];
```

Copy only some elements to another objects, I looked at the web but I don´t found a similar topic

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow, we would be happy to help you, please read this once [**Asking Help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that we know what is the exact problem you face

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: also the key words you wish to search on in this case are probably something like "json object delete element" which would lead you to a posting like this which has the elements to solve your problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451290/remove-element-from-json-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like any of the below solutions:

```
const keys = ["titulo" , "categoria","descripcion"];
arrLinks2 = arrLinks.map(item =>{
    let obj = {} ;
    keys.forEach(key =>{
        if(item[key]){
            obj[key] = item[key];
        }
    });
    return obj;
})
```

or

```
arrLinks2 =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrLinks)).map(item => {
    delete item.fecha;
    return item;
})
```

Comment: Thank you @SAYOOJ V R that was exactly i was looking

Answer (score 0):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator `...` to get rest properties:

```
const result = arrLinks.map(({fecha, ...other}) => ({...other}))
console.log(result);
```

An example:

```js
let arrLinks = [

{
    titulo: "CUADERNO DE BONOS SEGUROS BX+ 2020",
    fecha: "2020-02-18 11:02:41.0",
    categoria: "BONOS E INCENTIVOS",
    descripcion: "Cuaderno de Bonos e Incentivos"
},
{
    titulo: "ACTUALIZACIÓN TARIFA AUTOS / PICKUP 2019",
    fecha: "2019-07-22 10:57:43.0",
    categoria: "CIRCULARES",
    descripcion: "Actualización de tarifa para Seguro de Auto 
        B×+ y Seguro de Pick Up B×+ 2019"
},
  {
    titulo: "AVISO DE ACCIDENTES O ENFERMEDAD - GMM",
    fecha: "2019-09-18 12:42:45.0",
    categoria: "SINIESTROS PERSONAS",
    descripcion: "Aviso de Accidentes o Enfermedad Gastos Médicos Mayores"
  }
];

const result = arrLinks.map(({fecha, ...other}) => ({...other}))
console.log(result);
```